# Как забрать определённую роль у всех пользователей, кому она была выдана?

Tags: node.js, discord

Всем привет. Есть бот, который при нажатии на реакцию выдаёт роль, роль нужна для определенного действия. Когда действие не актуально, я пишу команду, и хочу чтобы удалялись роли  у всех пользователей, у которых она есть. Версия discord.js 11.4.2, уже перебрал все возможные варианты, рабочий:

```
  let mafiarole = message.guild.roles.find(x => x.name === "RoleName");
  await message.member.removeRole(mafiarole);
```

Но удаляет он только у меня, у других не может. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

CodeGPT зарешал.

Решение

```
  const guild = client.guilds.get('ServerID');
  
  // Получение роли по ее ID
  const role = guild.roles.get('RoleID');

  // Перебор всех участников сервера
  guild.members.forEach(member => {
    // Удаление роли у участника
    member.removeRole(role)
      .then(() => console.log(`Removed role from ${member.user.tag}`))
      .catch(console.error);
  });
```